# Google Maps API v3 Geodecoder country

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

How would you limit your search to a county in below query?

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
```

I've tried formatting an object like this:

```
{
    address: '389 george st, sydney'
    county: au
}
```

But if I search for 'poo' for instance India comes up in the results. How would I limit to only search in Australia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do region code biasing.

The query must be specific to the area you want to search.

This is the example given by Google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-region-es

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the region settings goes into the script in <head> as an argument - and not passed along the search query.